# Putting images in specific place without position:absolute

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've looked for a solution for this but can't find nothing,
Basically, what I've done is used the html map tag and used an image of a gameboy advance for the image, I've done all the areas so that it seems as if the buttons are clickable, what I want to know is if there is an easy way to get the images I want in the slideshow in the centre of the gameboy screen? For a clearer view on what I mean, this is what it is..
http://retrogamez.webege.com/

Any help will be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: Could you tell us why you don't want to use `position: absolute`?

Comment: I tried using position:absolute before on my home computer and obviously it looked fine when I used it from this computer, but when I got to work, the screen size is bigger and it was a completely different place

Comment: If it is in a different place based off of monitor size your doing it wrong.

Comment: position:absolute work good for all screen size.Review your css

Comment: If he is using position absolute, without using a position on divs parent, he will get trouble on screen sizes...

Comment: Use position absolute, but make the #maincontent DIV with the gameboy in position:relative; that will mean that the position of the absolute DIV relates to that #maincontent DIV, rather than the body.
I'd suggest reading the first part of my post on another forum:
http://www.htmlforums.com/showpost.php?p=829410&postcount=16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not use the position absolute correct. The parent of your image need a position otherwise he will use the screen size as a base.

```
#maincontent{
    position: relative;
}
#maincontent > .img-game{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px; /* just a example I dont know the right value */
    left: 50%; /* just a example I dont know the right value */
}
```

Comment: Nothing bro if you get any trouble just come back :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `position:relative`. Then center it within the `div` tag the `img` tag is in; that way the image will always be in the center of the div no matter the screen size.